# How can I effectively represent or model a locking sequence?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, locking, file-locking, concurrent-programming

The problem I am currently solving requires the use of two or more locks (file locks in this case) to avoid concurrency issues.

However I am having trouble representing the (locking) model I will use for the solution.

I.e. I would like to explain the problem and the solution I am coding via some type of diagram that lets me display the locking sequence, the concurrency implications (e.g. if we release this lock before this one we will have this problem, etc) and other such useful information.

What would be a good way to represent lock models?

I have been trying to do so with a flow diagram on one hand, so  I can show the code flow that leads me to either having to obtain a lock or not (e.g. I use an exclusive non-blocking lock to determine if a process is already monitoring a file, and if not I start the monitor), and on the other hand I've been thinking that a sequence diagram would do, but I am not satisfied with the results.

Are there any other visual tools available that would let me represent this problem?

How do engineers solve this issue for really complex problems like distributed systems and such?

Is there any one diagram for this or is it more like a collection of diagrams that are used to describe this?

Comment: If you ask Google, it's [a collection](https://www.google.com/search?q=readers+writers+problem&source=lnms&tbm=isch) (but then again, what is not a collection in the eyes of Google?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Petri nets**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petri_net) are historically used for modeling concurrency (and concurrent distributed systems). Being a formal mathematical concept they allow you to reason about operation sequences, state reachability (can be handy for example for proving an unacceptable configuration of locks and/or resource states never occurs), liveness, boundedness, deadlocking and other such useful information rigorously. Moreover they have nice and clean visual representation.
But using Petri nets one has to work with low level notions like places and transitions and there are no means for abstract modelling. In consequence their visual depiction usually becomes huge even for problems of middle size. Coloured, prioritized, timed and other augmented Petri nets come to rescue sometimes, but for more complex abstract systems [**UML statecharts**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UML_state_machine) fit better.

Here are some illustrations concerning locking sequence analysis using Petri nets (see the publications for more details):

1. a Petri net modelling of two-phase locking strategy from ["Petri net
   Based Model for Concurrent Control of Database System" by  HOD Jie,
   LI Fengying and WANG Huijiao](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=5657091)
2. a Petri net model for sharing strategy for a wafer flow pattern from
   ["Scheduling Single-Armed Cluster Tools With Reentrant Wafer Flows"
   by Hwan-Yong Lee and Tae-Eog Lee](http://koasas.kaist.ac.kr/bitstream/10203/1698/1/23_Reentrant%20Cluster%20Tool.pdf) (this one contains a 
   detailed  deadlock analysis)

[image: a Petri net modelling of two-phase locking strategy from "Petri net Based Model for Concurrent Control of Database System" by HOD Jie, LI Fengying and WANG Huijiao] [image: "Scheduling Single-Armed Cluster Tools With Reentrant Wafer Flows" by Hwan-Yong Lee and Tae-Eog Lee]

Comment: This is what I was looking for. In the end it seems it's really not that easy to represent such complex interactions, but this is the closest thing I can think of for what I was looking for. It definitely doesn't seem easy to use but at least there's bound to be documentation and papers and such. Those statecharts as well look useful enough to give them a try.

Comment: You should also consider an interactive, dynamic Petri Net model. It may be helpful to you and your audience if you can step through the algorithm on cue and see the state changes. For example, here is an interactive, dynamic version of Lee and Lee’s “Petri Net model for sharing strategy for wafer flow pattern”: http://www.aespen.ca/AEnswers/1448340750.pdf.

Answer (score 1):

For really complex lock-free algorithms verification, there is no such a visualization which would help to prove its correctness. Instead, there are tools available for the formal verification of multi-threaded software applications.

E.g. please take a look at [Spin](http://spinroot.com/spin/whatispin.html) which is designed to verify each combination of concurrently executed threads. One example of such a model for Spin is the following:

```
// a small example spin model
// Peterson's solution to the mutual exclusion problem (1981)

bool turn, flag[2];     // the shared variables, booleans
byte ncrit;             // nr of procs in critical section

active [2] proctype user()  // two processes
{
    assert(_pid == 0 || _pid == 1);
again:
    flag[_pid] = 1;
    turn = _pid;
    (flag[1 - _pid] == 0 || turn == 1 - _pid);

    ncrit++;
    assert(ncrit == 1); // critical section
    ncrit--;

    flag[_pid] = 0;
    goto again
}
// analysis: 
// $ spin -a peterson.pml
// $ cc -o pan pan.c
// $ ./pan
```

Here you describe the way how threads communicate and define conditions of expected program state. If any of the possible execution combination leads to an assertion failure, the it will be reported along with the control flow which leads to it.

Comment: This is an interesting project and it definitely seems like it would be nice to use the tool, however for my particular use case I actually need to present the information to someone else, not only to verify the correctness but to explain what's going on and why the issue I'm having is happening.

Answer (score 1):

I should have started with multiple UML sequence diagrams (one for each contention case) with clever usage of markers (color, annotation, fragment, OCL).

Real-time systems used to be designed with a lot of timing diagrams. But I'm not used to.

Most of the time, I have a good mind map of my code and I ask myself for each instruction, what happens if any thread is running at this time, what are the forbidden states. It's very similar to [Design by contract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract) (contracts that can be shown up on a sequence diagram through "markers".

Each time I've work with concurrent code, when well designed you just have focus on critical fragments (which are limited to few lines of codes).

Comment: I think that's a good start and a sequence diagram is what I've been actually using. In the end though, the sequence is in my mind and I go through all potential states/combinations. And that's precisely what I would like to be able to present to someone outside of my mind :) Timing diagrams seems like something I could look into.

Comment: Funny part, you can also give a try to animations. Ex : http://www.jconcurrent.com/

Answer (score 1):

Describing this locking microarchitecture may require two or three views on the mechanism. One might be a state diagram (Here's an example, elegantly illustrating the Java 6 Thread States and Lifecycle) [Thread States](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/examples/java-6-thread-state-machine-diagram-example.html).

A sequence diagram might illustrate the polling behavior of your monitor--assuming that your monitor is serializing resource access and granting multiple read locks to read requests but singular access to write requests. In this case you might illustrate that if there are outstanding read requests, the write request is blocked until all reads complete -- while still showing that the write request is queued in priority order so as not to wait indefinitely. (Sorry, I'm making a lot of assumptions about your algorithm, but many pessimistic algorithms operate in this fashion).

Lastly, a UML swimlane diagram might nicely shows the concurrent activities of various agents -- read and write requests, the monitor, and so on.

One of the best books I have found on software architectures is ["Documenting Software Architectures, Views and Beyond"](http://resources.sei.cmu.edu/library/asset-view.cfm?assetid=30386) . You will find it well worth your time (IMHO).

Cheers! Wonderful problem!

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I will take a look at that book, it looks interesting.